# Pass arguments from one powershell script to another

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have one powershell script, like this one:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$WORKDIR=$args[0]

Write-Host "Num of arguments given: " $args.Count

$AllArguments = ""
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $args.Count; $i += 2) {
    $AllArguments = '$AllArguments $args[$i] "$($args[$i+1])"'
}

Write-Host "AllArguments: $($AllArguments)"

Write-Host "Starting .\someotherscript.ps1 in directory $($WORKDIR)"

pushd "$WORKDIR"

& Powershell -File .\someotherscript.ps1 $AllArguments

popd
```

Basically, this powershell script shoud start another powershell script, but without the first argument. So, e.g. when this script is started with `.\firstscript.ps1 C:\some\dir -GiveMeParameter param1`, then it should call the other script with the following parameters `.\someotherscript.ps1 -GivMeParameter param1`.

How to achieve that? At the moment I do not know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple assignment to extract the first and remaining arguments by doing

```
$WORKDIR, $RemainingArgs = $args
```

I'm not sure why you're calling PowerShell again to run the script. You can just run the script directly and use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) to pass the remaining args to the child script.

```
.\someotherscript.ps1 @RemainingArgs
```